# google maps glitch on motorola phones

Tags: android, google-maps

On the Motorola Bravo, at the left bottom of a MapView, there is an ugly orange square rather than the google logo.  I notice this not only on my app, but on say, Yelp -- see screen shot:

[image]

Has anyone else seen this, and is there a workaround?  I don't know if it happens on other motorola phones, but I'm guessing it does because there is another, similar problem with a missing image on google maps, which is easy enough to solve and [documented elsewhere](http://dimitar.me/applications-that-use-the-mylocationoverlay-class-crash-on-the-new-droid-x/) as being on Droid phones as well.

Comment: Interesting one. Wish I could help. Maybe some bug with png rendering? (I'm assuming their logo is a png, perhaps not)

Comment: Are you using a custom rom? What carrier did you get it from? Did you modify any of the system files? I have no problems on my Verizon branded phone. Either with the stock firmware or cyanogen.

Comment: It's at&t, I didn't modify anything on it, although technically my client bought the phone for development purposes, it's not my personal phone.  I'm pretty sure they didn't modify anything though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i found out, hope it helps at least a bit.

I have a Motorola Milestone (it is the EU version of the Droid as you probably know) with vodafone branded rom (so no ported custom rom) and do not have this 'bug' at all. 
Here are some screens of Google Maps and Yelp...

[image] 
[image]

so I do not have this problem at all but that does not mean other Milestone users do not have it. Maybe it is because of a missing image in one of the operators firmware files - when they customize their roms, they may delete some google-specific images and then forget to replace them with their own images (or put an ugly orange png at this place).

So I'm afraid I can't help any further, but at least i could show that this is not necessarily a motorola problem but maybe a provider problem?!

you could have written that you already posted this to motorola developers forum so i would have saved the time to look at this resource ;) [click](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Glitch-with-Google-logo-in-Google-maps/m-p/10568#M2085)

edit: i found a post at modaco forum where a user describes the orange square as a bug in a custom rom --> [the post](http://android.modaco.com/content/acer-liquid-liquid-modaco-com/305959/fastboot-failed-when-updating-rom-problem-solved/). this is on acer liquid.

Comment: hmm, well that's interesting that at least one other person ran into it, and not on motorola.  I can work around it by enlarging the maps so the logo is out of sight, and then just putting a google logo there to stay under googles terms-of-service radar....but I wish I could at least tell which devices I need to do it on.

Comment: well, i do not have enough devices for you to test ;) i think it would be the best way to stick to the motodev forum, at least they should know something about this. it is quite unbelievable that noone else has this problem if you have it.

Comment: Well you didn't exactly solve my problem but I appreciate your help.  Yeah I'll see what happens on the motodev forum but I'm not counting on much help.