# Blank square in Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm writing application for Android 2.1. with Google Maps. Everything works fine except one detail: there is a white square box on the bottom left corner of devices screen. (like on the screenshot below). This is independent on my location - always bottom left corner is blank.

Here is java code, where I create mapView:

```
mapView = new MapView(activity,"myCorrectApiCode");

// Configure the map display options
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
mapView.setSatellite(true);
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

Any idea to exclude this blank square?

[image]

code details:
my main activity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMain"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
android:background="@drawable/mapback"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMainUp"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80sp" android:gravity="center">
    <TextView android:textColor="#000000" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/TextViewResultTxt" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/result_txt" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:textColor="#000000" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/myLocationText" android:singleLine="true" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/hello"></TextView>
    <TextView android:textColor="#000000" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/myLocationTextDist" android:singleLine="true" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/waiting_for_gps"></TextView><TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/timerTextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

mapView I'm adding dynamic:

```
LinearLayout l = ((LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutMain));
l.addView(mapView);
```

Comment: yes, Motorola Milestone XT720

Comment: As i know, it is common issue on some Motorola phones. (http://android.bigresource.com/Track/android-V90Io6p0T/), and, as i can see, it is somehow related to Cyanogenmod (http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=395)

Comment: You are right. On another devices (not Motorola) my application works fine. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is device-dependend.

Answered here: [google maps glitch on motorola phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522108/google-maps-glitch-on-motorola-phones)

Post in official Motorola forum: 
http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Glitch-with-Google-logo-in-Google-maps/m-p/10568#M2085

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I work around it and I set mapView width as 2*screen width (as it was described in linked StackOverfolow question) .

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, I would first guess that you might have another MapView element (or some other element) defined in your XML file that is placed on top of the current map view. If you can share more on how you show your map (XML and java) it would be easier to find the cause.

Comment: This link shows a user who was able to fix the blank square issue: http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=395