# Portion of google map being cut in Motorola Milestone?

Tags: android

When we create google map in our application and load in motorola milestone, left side a square portion is being cut off. Can anyone what may be the reason? The same code wont show any issues in other sets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you [google maps glitch on motorola phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522108/google-maps-glitch-on-motorola-phones)

And its a known bug in some of motorola phones